# Prefix MongoDB collection names with pymongo

Tags: pymongo

I want separate environments on a single MongoDB database.

How can I prefix my collections dynamically?

For example, something with an option on MongoClient:

```py
client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URI, prefix="devenv1")
db = client[DB_NAME]

db.users.find() # -> would transparently run db.devenv1_users.find()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.find()
```

is synonymous with

```
db['users'].find()
```

and also:

```
collection = 'users'
db[collection].find()
```

So now you can control the collection name through a variable and set it to whatever prefix you like.

Comment: thanks for your answer. that means rewriting all the calls, and there's hundreds and that would not be very readable. I looking for something once for all, as easy as changing the database.

Comment: There's no "quick fix" option to do this. You could use different databases.